# How to implement a particle engine

Tags: python, refactoring, pygame, particle-system

So I have made a particle engine for smoke that I'm pretty happy with I think it fits my game pretty well.
I now need to implement it into my game and I'm having a little bit of trouble. I was wondering if someone could explain how I would go about using my particle engine in my game.
I added the both my codes(for smoke and my game file) below.
I want to keep the particles separate from the game files but call it in my game.
Eventually, I want to make more particle effects in the engine that I could also call.

Can someone help? It might need a little bit of tweaking to work.

**PARTICLE CODE:**

```
import pygame,random
from pygame.locals import *

xmax = 1000    #width of window
ymax = 600     #height of window

class Smoke():
    def __init__(self, startx, starty, col):
        self.x = startx
        self.y = random.randint(0, starty)
        self.col = col
        self.sx = startx
        self.sy = starty

    def move(self):
        if self.y < 0:
            self.x = self.sx
            self.y = self.sy
        else:
            self.y -= 1
        self.x += random.randint(-1, 2)

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((xmax,ymax))
    black = (0,0,0)
    grey = (145,145,145)
    light_grey = (192,192,192)
    dark_grey = (183, 183, 183)

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    particles = []
    for part in range(600):
        if part % 2 > 0: col = grey
        #elif part % 5 > 0: col = dark_grey
        elif part % 3 > 0: col = dark_grey
        else: col = light_grey
        particles.append( Smoke(0, 500, col) )

    exitflag = False
    while not exitflag:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                exitflag = True
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    exitflag = True

        screen.fill(black)
        for p in particles:
            p.move()
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, p.col, (p.x, p.y), 15)

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(80)
    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**GAME CODE**

```
import pygame
from pygame import *

WIN_WIDTH = 1120 - 320
WIN_HEIGHT = 960 - 320
HALF_WIDTH = int(WIN_WIDTH / 2)
HALF_HEIGHT = int(WIN_HEIGHT / 2)

DISPLAY = (WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT)
DEPTH = 0
FLAGS = 0
CAMERA_SLACK = 30

levels = {0: {'level': [
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                         E  ",
                    "                            PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "               PPPPP        PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPP           P",
                    "                            PPPP           P",
                    "                            PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "                      PPPPPPPPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "       PPPP                 PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "PPPPP                       PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "PPP                         PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "PPP                         PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "PPP                         PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "PPP         PPPPP           PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "PPP                                     PPPP",
                    "PPP                                     PPPP",
                    "PPP                                     PPPP",
                    "PPP                       PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "PPP                       PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",],
             'enemies': [(9, 38)]},
             1: {'level': [
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                         E  ",
                    "                            PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "               PPPPP        PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPP           P",
                    "                            PPPP           P",
                    "                            PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "                      PPPPPPPPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "       PPPP                 PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "PPPPP                       PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "PPP                  PPPPPPPPPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "PPP                         PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "PPP                         PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "PPP             PPPPPPPP    PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "PPP                                     PPPP",
                    "PPP                                     PPPP",
                    "PPP          PPPPP                      PPPP",
                    "PPP          P            PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "PPP          P    PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",],
             'enemies': [(9, 38), (18, 38), (15, 15)]}}

class Scene(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def render(self, screen):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def update(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def handle_events(self, events):
        raise NotImplementedError

class GameScene(Scene):
    def __init__(self, levelno):
        super(GameScene, self).__init__()
        self.bg = Surface((32,32))
        self.bg.convert()
        self.bg.fill(Color("#0094FF"))
        up = left = right = False
        self.entities = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.player = Player(5, 40)
        self.player.scene = self
        self.platforms = []

        self.levelno = levelno

        levelinfo = levels[levelno]
        self.enemies = [Enemy(*pos) for pos in levelinfo['enemies']]

        level = levelinfo['level']
        total_level_width = len(level[0]) * 32
        total_level_height = len(level) * 32

        # build the level
        x = 0
        y = 0
        for row in level:
            for col in row:
                if col == "P":
                    p = Platform(x, y)
                    self.platforms.append(p)
                    self.entities.add(p)
                if col == "E":
                    e = ExitBlock(x, y)
                    self.platforms.append(e)
                    self.entities.add(e)
                x += 32
            y += 32
            x = 0

        self.camera = Camera(complex_camera, total_level_width, total_level_height)
        self.entities.add(self.player)
        for e in self.enemies:
            self.entities.add(e)

    def render(self, screen):
        for y in range(20):
            for x in range(25):
                screen.blit(self.bg, (x * 32, y * 32))

        for e in self.entities:
            screen.blit(e.image, self.camera.apply(e))

    def update(self):
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        up, left, right = [pressed[key] for key in (K_UP, K_LEFT, K_RIGHT)]
        self.player.update(up, left, right, self.platforms)

        for e in self.enemies:
            e.update(self.platforms)

        self.camera.update(self.player)

    def exit(self):
        if self.levelno+1 in levels:
            self.manager.go_to(GameScene(self.levelno+1))
        else:
            self.manager.go_to(CustomScene("You win!"))

    def die(self):
        self.manager.go_to(CustomScene("You lose!"))

    def handle_events(self, events):
        for e in events:
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_ESCAPE:
                self.manager.go_to(TitleScene())

class CustomScene(object):

    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text
        super(CustomScene, self).__init__()
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 56)

    def render(self, screen):
        # ugly! 
        screen.fill((0, 200, 0))
        text1 = self.font.render(self.text, True, (255, 255, 255))
        screen.blit(text1, (200, 50))

    def update(self):
        pass

    def handle_events(self, events):
        for e in events:
            if e.type == KEYDOWN:
                self.manager.go_to(TitleScene())

class TitleScene(object):

    def __init__(self):
        super(TitleScene, self).__init__()
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 56)
        self.sfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 32)

    def render(self, screen):
        # ugly! 
        screen.fill((0, 200, 0))
        text1 = self.font.render('Crazy Game', True, (255, 255, 255))
        text2 = self.sfont.render('> press space to start <', True, (255, 255, 255))
        screen.blit(text1, (200, 50))
        screen.blit(text2, (200, 350))

    def update(self):
        pass

    def handle_events(self, events):
        for e in events:
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_SPACE:
                self.manager.go_to(GameScene(0))

class SceneMananger(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.go_to(TitleScene())

    def go_to(self, scene):
        self.scene = scene
        self.scene.manager = self

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(DISPLAY, FLAGS, DEPTH)
    pygame.display.set_caption("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
    timer = pygame.time.Clock()
    running = True

    manager = SceneMananger()

    while running:
        timer.tick(60)

        if pygame.event.get(QUIT):
            running = False
            return
        manager.scene.handle_events(pygame.event.get())
        manager.scene.update()
        manager.scene.render(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()

class Camera(object):
    def __init__(self, camera_func, width, height):
        self.camera_func = camera_func
        self.state = Rect(0, 0, width, height)

    def apply(self, target):
        try:
            return target.rect.move(self.state.topleft)
        except AttributeError:
            return map(sum, zip(target, self.state.topleft))

    def update(self, target):
        self.state = self.camera_func(self.state, target.rect)

def complex_camera(camera, target_rect):
    l, t, _, _ = target_rect
    _, _, w, h = camera
    l, t, _, _ = -l + HALF_WIDTH, -t +HALF_HEIGHT, w, h

    l = min(0, l)                           # stop scrolling left
    l = max(-(camera.width - WIN_WIDTH), l)   # stop scrolling right
    t = max(-(camera.height-WIN_HEIGHT), t) # stop scrolling bottom

    return Rect(l, t, w, h)

class Entity(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

class Player(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.xvel = 0
        self.yvel = 0
        self.onGround = False
        self.image = Surface((32,32))
        self.image.fill(Color("#0000FF"))
        self.image.convert()
        self.rect = Rect(x*32, y*32, 32, 32)

    def update(self, up, left, right, platforms):
        if self.rect.top > 1440 or self.rect.top < 0:
            self.scene.die()
        if self.rect.left > 1408 or self.rect.right < 0:
            self.scene.die()
        if up:
            if self.onGround:
                self.yvel = 0
                self.yvel -= 10 # only jump if on the ground
        if left:
            self.xvel = -10
        if right:
            self.xvel = 10
        if not self.onGround:
            self.yvel += 0.3 # only accelerate with gravity if in the air
            if self.yvel > 80: self.yvel = 80 # max falling speed
        if not(left or right):
            self.xvel = 0

        self.rect.left += self.xvel # increment in x direction
        if self.collide(self.xvel, 0, platforms): # do x-axis collisions
            self.rect.top += self.yvel # increment in y direction
            self.onGround = False; # assuming we're in the air
            self.collide(0, self.yvel, platforms) # do y-axis collisions

    def collide(self, xvel, yvel, platforms):
        for p in platforms:
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, p):
                if isinstance(p, ExitBlock):
                    self.scene.exit()
                    return False
                if xvel > 0: self.rect.right = p.rect.left
                if xvel < 0: self.rect.left = p.rect.right
                if yvel > 0:
                    self.rect.bottom = p.rect.top
                    self.onGround = True
                if yvel < 0:
                    self.rect.top = p.rect.bottom
        return True

class Enemy(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.yVel = 0
        self.xVel = 2 # start moving immediately
        self.image = Surface((32,32))
        self.image.fill(Color("#00FF00"))
        self.image.convert()
        self.rect = Rect(x*32, y*32, 32, 32)
        self.onGround = False

    def update(self, platforms):
        if not self.onGround:
            self.yVel += 0.3

        # no need for right_dis to be a member of the class,
        # since we know we are moving right if self.xVel > 0
        right_dis = self.xVel > 0

        # create a point at our left (or right) feet 
        # to check if we reached the end of the platform
        m = (1, 1) if right_dis else (-1, 1)
        p = self.rect.bottomright if right_dis else self.rect.bottomleft
        fp = map(sum, zip(m, p))

        # if there's no platform in front of us, change the direction
        collide = any(p for p in platforms if p.rect.collidepoint(fp))
        if not collide:
            self.xVel *= -1

        self.rect.left += self.xVel # increment in x direction
        self.collide(self.xVel, 0, platforms) # do x-axis collisions
        self.rect.top += self.yVel # increment in y direction
        self.onGround = False; # assuming we're in the air
        self.collide(0, self.yVel, platforms) # do y-axis collisions

    def collide(self, xVel, yVel, platforms):
        for p in platforms:
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, p):
                if xVel > 0: 
                    self.rect.right = p.rect.left
                    self.xVel *= -1 # hit wall, so change direction
                if xVel < 0: 
                    self.rect.left = p.rect.right
                    self.xVel *= -1 # hit wall, so change direction
                if yVel > 0:
                    self.rect.bottom = p.rect.top
                    self.onGround = True
                if yVel < 0:
                    self.rect.top = p.rect.bottom

class Platform(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        #self.image = Surface([32, 32], pygame.SRCALPHA, 32) #makes blocks invisible for much better artwork
        self.image = Surface((32,32)) #makes blocks visible for building levels
        self.image.convert()
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 32, 32)

    def update(self):
        pass

class ExitBlock(Platform):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Platform.__init__(self, x, y)
        self.image = Surface((32,32)) #makes blocks visible for building levels
        self.image.convert()
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 32, 32)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: For making other particle effects, make classes for them like your smoke class.  For adding them in, I can give you an overview, but the actual thing is much too complex.  You need to add two arguments to the move function, x movement and y movement (in other words, how far the background moved since it was last updated), and have the particles move that amount.  It shouldn't be that hard for you since you understand the code.  Create the smoke just like I showed you in the other question.  GL.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Beware! Long post!

### The particle

First, let's take a look at your `Smoke` class. It contains some of the *smoke* behaviour, but also your main loop does. Let's fix that by creating a generic `Particle` class that does nothing but represent a particle:

```
class Particle():
    def __init__(self, col, size, *strategies):
        self.x, self.y = 0, 0
        self.col = col
        self.alive = 0
        self.strategies = strategies
        self.size = size

    def kill(self):
        self.alive = -1 # alive -1 means dead

    def move(self):
        for s in self.strategies:
            s(self)
```

This class does not do much. It is generic in a way that all it's behaviour (simple functions) is passed to its `__init__` function, and the particle applies these functions to itself in the `move` method.

### The behaviour of particles

Now that our particle class is flexible, let's think about how particles should behave so that a bunch of it look like smoke.

A smoke particle should ascend, so let's create a function that moves the particle upwards:

```
def ascending(speed):
    def _ascending(particle):
        particle.y -= speed
    return _ascending
```

A smoke particle should die at some point, so let's write a function that kills at a certain condition:

```
def kill_at(max_x, max_y):
    def _kill_at(particle):
        if particle.x < -max_x or particle.x > max_x or particle.y < -max_y or particle.y > max_y:
            particle.kill()
    return _kill_at
```

We need to keep track how long a particle is alive (comes in handy later), so we need a function that let a particle *age*:

```
def age(amount):
    def _age(particle):
        particle.alive += amount
    return _age
```

When the smoke ascends, it should not do it in a straight line (how boring!), but it should fan out:

```
def fan_out(modifier):
    def _fan_out(particle):
        d = particle.alive / modifier
        d += 1
        particle.x += random.randint(-d, d)
    return _fan_out
```

Nice! Now our smoke can fan out, but it's still a little boring, so let's write a function that simulates a little wind:

```
def wind(direction, strength):
    def _wind(particle):
        if random.randint(0,100) < strength:
            particle.x += direction
    return _wind
```

We have now a bunch of functions that describe the bahaviour of a particle. All of them are small and self-contained. You can create an infinity amount of them and combine them as you like to create different particles.

### The smoke

Time to create some particles actually: Enter the smoke machine!

```
def smoke_machine():
    colors = {0: grey,
              1: dark_grey,
              2: light_grey}
    def create():
        for _ in xrange(random.choice([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3])):
            behaviour = age(1), ascending(1), fan_out(400), wind(1, 15), kill_at(1000, 1000)
            p = Particle(colors[random.randint(0, 2)], random.randint(10, 15), *behaviour)
            yield p

    while True:
        yield create()
```

So what the hell is this? Easy. It's a generator that constantly emits new particles. Every time someone wants to retrieve the next item out if it, it calls its nested `create` function. That function in turn returns 0 to 3 particles, based on the input list to `random.choice`. It's a nice way to say that it returns 0 particles with a 70% chance, and 1, 2 or 3 particles with a 10% chance each.

In the next line we define the behaviour of the particle. It's just a tuple of functions. Note how each function call returns its nested function in return. This way these functions are parameterized.

The last step is to randomly assign a color and a size to the particle.

You can test it from the command line to see how it works:

```
>>> s=smoke_machine()
>>> list(next(s))
[]
>>> list(next(s))
[<particle.Particle instance at 0x02AD94B8>, <particle.Particle instance at 0x02
AD9030>]
>>> list(next(s))
[]
>>> list(next(s))
[]
>>> list(next(s))
[<particle.Particle instance at 0x02AD9030>]
>>> list(next(s))
[<particle.Particle instance at 0x02AD9418>, <particle.Particle instance at 0x02
AD93C8>]
>>> list(next(s))
[<particle.Particle instance at 0x02AD9030>]
```

See how every time we call next on the generator, it returns up to 3 particles.

### Putting it all together

How do we combine our smoke machine with our game? Let's write a class that handles it for us:

```
class Emitter(object):
    def __init__(self, pos=(0, 0)):
        self.particles = []
        self.pos = pos
        self.factories = []

    def add_factory(self, factory, pre_fill=300):
        self.factories.append(factory)
        tmp = []
        for _ in xrange(pre_fill):
            n = next(factory)
            tmp.extend(n)
            for p in tmp:
                p.move()
        self.particles.extend(tmp)

    def update(self):
        for f in self.factories:
            self.particles.extend(next(f))

        for p in self.particles[:]:
            p.move()
            if p.alive == -1:
                self.particles.remove(p)

    def draw(self, screen, position_translater_func):
        for p in self.particles:
            target_pos = position_translater_func(map(sum, zip((p.x, p.y), self.pos)))
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, p.col, target_pos, int(p.size))
```

The emitter can hold a bunch of factory functions (like our `smoke_machine`), can every time it's updated, it adds the particles of theses factories to its `self.particles` so it can draw them to the screen. Let's look at some functions in detail:

If we add a new factory with `add_factory`, we call that `factory` and move its particles 300 (or whatever `pre_fill` is) times in advance. This way, some particles are already there.

If we want to draw the particles, we have to calculate thier positions using the position of the `Emitter`. Also, we need to adjust this position using the camera of the game, so we just accept a function as parameter that translates our position to the correct final position so that our particles scroll accordingly within the game.

We don't need big changes to the game class to use the `Emitter` now. We just create a new list in the `GameScene` called `self.emitter`, and an `Emitter` and add the `smoke_machine` factory to it.

In the `render` method we call

```
for e in self.emitter:
    e.draw(screen, self.camera.apply)
```

and in the `update` method we call

```
for e in self.emitter:
   e.update()
```

and we are done!

### Action !

[image]

### complete listing:

#### game.py

*omitted some classes because I hit the 30000 character limit :-)*

```
import pygame
from pygame import *
from particle import Emitter, smoke_machine
WIN_WIDTH = 1120 - 320
WIN_HEIGHT = 960 - 320
HALF_WIDTH = int(WIN_WIDTH / 2)
HALF_HEIGHT = int(WIN_HEIGHT / 2)

DISPLAY = (WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT)
DEPTH = 0
FLAGS = 0
CAMERA_SLACK = 30

levels = {0: {'level': [
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                         E  ",
                    "                            PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "               PPPPP        PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPP           P",
                    "                            PPPP           P",
                    "                            PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "                      PPPPPPPPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "       PPPP                 PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "PPPPP                       PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "PPP                         PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "PPP                         PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "PPP                         PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "PPP         PPPPP           PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "PPP                                     PPPP",
                    "PPP                                     PPPP",
                    "PPP                                     PPPP",
                    "PPP                       PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "PPP                       PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP    S      PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",],
             'enemies': [(9, 38)]},
             1: {'level': [
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                         E  ",
                    "                            PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "               PPPPP        PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPP           P",
                    "                            PPPP           P",
                    "                            PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "                      PPPPPPPPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "       PPPP                 PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "PPPPP                       PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "PPP                  PPPPPPPPPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "PPP                         PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "PPP                         PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "PPP             PPPPPPPP    PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "PPP                                     PPPP",
                    "PPP                                     PPPP",
                    "PPP          PPPPP                      PPPP",
                    "PPP          P            PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "PPP          P    PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",],
             'enemies': [(9, 38), (18, 38), (15, 15)]}}

...

class GameScene(Scene):
    def __init__(self, levelno):
        super(GameScene, self).__init__()
        self.bg = Surface((32,32))
        self.bg.convert()
        self.bg.fill(Color("#0094FF"))
        up = left = right = False
        self.entities = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.player = Player(5, 40)
        self.player.scene = self
        self.platforms = []

        self.levelno = levelno

        levelinfo = levels[levelno]
        self.enemies = [Enemy(*pos) for pos in levelinfo['enemies']]

        level = levelinfo['level']
        total_level_width = len(level[0]) * 32
        total_level_height = len(level) * 32

        self.emitter = []

        # build the level
        x = 0
        y = 0
        for row in level:
            for col in row:
                if col == "P":
                    p = Platform(x, y)
                    self.platforms.append(p)
                    self.entities.add(p)
                if col == "E":
                    e = ExitBlock(x, y)
                    self.platforms.append(e)
                    self.entities.add(e)
                if col == "S":
                    e = Emitter((x, total_level_height))
                    e.add_factory(smoke_machine())
                    self.emitter.append(e)
                x += 32
            y += 32
            x = 0

        self.camera = Camera(complex_camera, total_level_width, total_level_height)
        self.entities.add(self.player)
        for e in self.enemies:
            self.entities.add(e)

    def render(self, screen):
        for y in range(20):
            for x in range(25):
                screen.blit(self.bg, (x * 32, y * 32))

        for e in self.emitter:
            e.draw(screen, self.camera.apply)

        for e in self.entities:
            screen.blit(e.image, self.camera.apply(e))

    def update(self):
        for e in self.emitter:
            e.update()

        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        up, left, right = [pressed[key] for key in (K_UP, K_LEFT, K_RIGHT)]
        self.player.update(up, left, right, self.platforms)

        for e in self.enemies:
            e.update(self.platforms)

        self.camera.update(self.player)

    def exit(self):
        if self.levelno+1 in levels:
            self.manager.go_to(GameScene(self.levelno+1))
        else:
            self.manager.go_to(CustomScene("You win!"))

    def die(self):
        self.manager.go_to(CustomScene("You lose!"))

    def handle_events(self, events):
        for e in events:
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_ESCAPE:
                self.manager.go_to(TitleScene())

...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

#### particle.py

```
import pygame,random

def ascending(speed):
    def _ascending(particle):
        particle.y -= speed
    return _ascending

def kill_at(max_x, max_y):
    def _kill_at(particle):
        if particle.x < -max_x or particle.x > max_x or particle.y < -max_y or particle.y > max_y:
            particle.kill()
    return _kill_at

def age(amount):
    def _age(particle):
        particle.alive += amount
    return _age

def fan_out(modifier):
    def _fan_out(particle):
        d = particle.alive / modifier
        d += 1
        particle.x += random.randint(-d, d)
    return _fan_out

def wind(direction, strength):
    def _wind(particle):
        if random.randint(0,100) < strength:
            particle.x += direction
    return _wind

class Particle():
    def __init__(self, col, size, *strategies):
        self.x, self.y = 0, 0
        self.col = col
        self.alive = 0
        self.strategies = strategies
        self.size = size

    def kill(self):
        self.alive = -1 # alive -1 means dead

    def move(self):
        for s in self.strategies:
            s(self)        

black = (0,0,0)
grey = (145,145,145)
light_grey = (192,192,192)
dark_grey = (183, 183, 183)

def smoke_machine():
    colors = {0: grey,
              1: dark_grey,
              2: light_grey}
    def create():
        for _ in xrange(random.choice([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3])):
            behaviour = ascending(1), kill_at(1000, 1000), fan_out(400), wind(1, 15), age(1)
            p = Particle(colors[random.randint(0, 2)], random.randint(10, 15), *behaviour)
            yield p

    while True:
        yield create()

class Emitter(object):
    def __init__(self, pos=(0, 0)):
        self.particles = []
        self.pos = pos
        self.factories = []

    def add_factory(self, factory, pre_fill=300):
        self.factories.append(factory)
        tmp = []
        for _ in xrange(pre_fill):
            n = next(factory)
            tmp.extend(n)
            for p in tmp:
                p.move()
        self.particles.extend(tmp)

    def update(self):
        for f in self.factories:
            self.particles.extend(next(f))

        for p in self.particles[:]:
            p.move()
            if p.alive == -1:
                self.particles.remove(p)

    def draw(self, screen, position_translater_func):
        for p in self.particles:
            target_pos = position_translater_func(map(sum, zip((p.x, p.y), self.pos)))
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, p.col, target_pos, int(p.size))
```

### Conclusion

We have successfully integrated the particles in the game. We have done this by writting small, self-contained functions that describe different behavioral patterns, and composed them by using a factory function.

And while doing this, we learned about [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29), [generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_%28computer_science%29), the [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), the [factory-](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern) and the [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

We could now easily add new behaviours, e.g. changing colors, or create new particle factories that behave totally different, but use our exiting functions.

For example, try using this function that will let the particles grow

```
def grow(amount):
    def _grow(particle):
        if random.randint(0,100) < particle.alive / 20:
            particle.size += amount
    return _grow
```

by adding `grow(0.5)` to the list of behaviours in the `smoke_machine`

[image]

Small change, impressive effect.

What a nice day!

P.S.: You can find a faster version (and bugfixes) at [this repository](https://bitbucket.org/BigYellowCactus/particlegame). It uses [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/), [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html), [`psyco`](http://psyco.sourceforge.net/) and [`pygame.surfarray`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surfarray.html) and eschews the `random` module for massive speed improvement.

Comment: +1 Great (and long) answer, Really awesome! Great job with the factories and generators! Love this answer!

Comment: FYI, I also added some rain/wind effect to the code in the repository at bitbucket.

Comment: This is amazing! I have a question though, I copied and pasted the files over but nothing happens with what you put above, do I need to call it? or make a function for adding to emitter[]?

Comment: I removed some stuff from the listing because answers are limited to 30000 character. Just check out the source at the repo